# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION BillingCountry

Tags: field-integrity-exception

How can I tell if I should send the full country name or two letter ISO field, when creating accounts? I made an API call here and I see the billing country is a text field with a length of 80 characters:

https://x.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/account/describe

Here is my request and response:

POST https://x.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/account HTTP/1.1

```
{"name":"Loblaws Companies Ltd","phone":"+1.905.459.2500","shippingCity":"Pickering","shippingCountry":"CA","shippingPostalCode":"L1W 4C1","shippingState":"Ontario","shippingStreet":"1400 Church Street","billingCity":"BRAMPTON","billingCountry":"CA","billingPostalCode":"L6Y 5S5","billingState":"Ontario","billingStreet":"1 PRESIDENTS CHOICE CIRCLE"}
```

Response

```
[{"message":"There's a problem with this country, even though it may appear correct. Please select a country/territory from the list of valid countries.: Billing Country","errorCode":"FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION","fields":["BillingCountry"]},{"message":"There's a problem with this country, even though it may appear correct. Please select a country/territory from the list of valid countries.: Shipping Country","errorCode":"FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION","fields":["ShippingCountry"]}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [State and country:There's a problem with this state, even though it may appear correct. Please select a state from the list of valid states](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231378/state-and-countrytheres-a-problem-with-this-state-even-though-it-may-appear-c)

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if State Country Picklist is enabled?